# 2 different builds with gradle: one spring boot and one non sping boot executables

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, executable-jar

I am new to gradle (6.4.1) and started a CLI executable jar.
It used to work.
Then I added a REST interface next to the CLI using spring boot. Spring boot is working but the CLI executable jar was broken. It always produce a spring boot executable. I need to keep both executable approaches.
To fix that I have created a separate build file dedicated to the CLI executable but the jar is not executable and errors with *"no main manifest attribute"*.
Can you please provide me with guidance to resolve my need.

tldr;
In order to successfully build with the second build file I have taken all dependencies from the spring boot build file but switched the spring boot plugin into a maven BOM approach to avoid to produce a spring boot only executable.

**Spring boot build file**

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'console.ConsoleExercices'
    }
}

group = 'be.challenge'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.4.0'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-servlet', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-jackson', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-swagger-java', version: '3.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-test', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}
```

**Executable CLI jar build file**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE' apply false
    id 'war'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'be.console.ConsoleExercises'
    }
    archivesBaseName = 'console-exercises'
}

group = 'be.challenge'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.4.0'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-servlet', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-jackson', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-swagger-java', version: '3.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-test', version: '3.4.0'
    compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [war plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)

```
disables the default JAR archive generation of the Java plugin
```

Remove the 'war' plugin to restore the jar archive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI project should make use of the [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin. It will make sure that it is fully runnable as a regular JAR/CLI application.

In addition to that, use `implementation` instead of `compile`. The `compile` configuration has long been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Thank you @francisco-mateo. I still have the same problem when using the application plugin. When running `gradle -b build-console.gradle clean assemble` and try to execute the jar `$ java -jar build/libs/multiplicationtable-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` it return the error 
__no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/multiplicationtable-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar__.
However running with the run task produces a start of expected behavior executing the main class but the CLI is interactive and this does not block waiting on user input

Comment: and thank you @fransisco-mateo for your remark on the `compile` deprecation